# Is it possible to create a loop with Hair Dynamics?

Tags: particles, physics, hair

I have a walk cycle of a character I created that uses hair strands with dynamics turned on.

I was wondering if it was possible to make the hair dynamics loop along with the animation. Because as of right now, every time the animation loops, the hair physics restart which looks strange.

Answer (score 0):

if you're able to have the forces on the hair dynamics be equal in the beginning and the end of the loop, you can bake the hair from a negative frame to get it to settle in the same position that it will be in on the final frame of the animation.

Answer (score -1):

Have you took a looks at this ?

https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?382857-Baking-scenes-with-fur-and-hair-dynamics-Library-linked-rigs

Might help...

Comment: That seems to be about baking Hair dynamics. That's not really what I'm looking for. I just want to make it loop with the rest of the animation.